# How to out while loop when button is disabled?

Tags: java, jmeter

I used WebDriver sampler and wrote a Selenium Java script- In below script

```
var x = 0
var nextt = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.xpath("//button[contains(@class,'btn btn-sm btn-light border ml-3')]"))
var nextisEnb = nextt.isEnabled()
while (true) {
  if (nextisEnb == true) {
    //if(next.isEnabled()){
    ++x
    //java.lang.Thread.sleep(2000);

    var wait9 = new org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, 9000)
    wait9.until(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(pkg.By.xpath("//button[contains(@class,'btn btn-sm btn-light border ml-3')]")))
    nextt.click();
    WDS.log.info('btn50-clicked ' + x + 'isEnabled=' + nextisEnb)

    //break
    if (nextisEnb == false) {

      break
    }
  }
}
```

When nextt button is disabled still it not break the loop . it still running in Jmeter. So how we can out for the loop?

I also used below code got same problem

```
var next = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.xpath("//button[contains(@class,'btn btn-sm btn-light border ml-3')]"))

while (next.isEnabled()) {
  java.lang.Thread.sleep(2000);

  var wait9 = new org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, 9000)
  wait9.until(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(pkg.By.xpath("//button[contains(@class,'btn btn-sm btn-light border ml-3')]")))
  next.click();
  WDS.log.info('btn50-400clicked')

}
WDS.log.info('btn2clicked')
//java.lang.Thread.sleep(3000);
if (!next.isEnabled()) {
  WDS.log.info('Next button disabled')
}
```

How is it resolved?

Comment: Hi there, I formatted your code and changed some tags as you are referring to Java, not JavaScript. Please keep that in mind for future questions.

Answer (score 0):

You're always querying the initial state of the "Next" button, you need to "find" it once again to get the "fresh" status after clicking. My expectation is that when you click the "Next" button the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) gets refreshed and the button has new properties and you have stored its previous state into a global variable.

```
next.click()
WDS.log.info('btn50-400clicked')

//here the page has refreshed and you need to "find" the button once again

next = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.xpath("//button[contains(@class,'btn btn-sm btn-light border ml-3')]"))

if (!next().isEnabled() {
    break
}
```

If anything goes wrong you can always [take a screenshot](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/TakesScreenshot.html) like:

```
var screenshot = WDS.browser.getScreenshotAs(pkg.OutputType.FILE)
screenshot.renameTo(new java.io.File('screenshot.png'))
```

or print the [current HTML source code](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#getPageSource()) of the page to [JMeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) like:

```
WDS.log.info(WDS.browser.getPageSource())
```

to check the button state either visually or by inspecting its HTML definition.

More information: [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-ten-questions-answered)